# Hide power options (Gnome 3)

Tags: gnome, power-management, 18.10

I have a problem with Gnome: I do not want people to shut down my laptop using the GUI (and all personnel who are authorized to shutdown, reboot, etc are **command line users**) so I want to disable power options under gnome3, ubuntu Cosmic Cuttlefish, 18.10. 
I am doing this so people wont shutdown my GUI server.

Comment: You may check here for an approach using polkit: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?313889-Disabling-shutdown-restart-for-a-user. If just hiding the power off button is enough, then this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1346/hide-shutdown-button/ may be sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gnome3: How to disable "Shutdown" button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179727/gnome3-how-to-disable-shutdown-button)